# SvelteKit button won't work with click outside function

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following `clickOutside` function that is working well

```
export function clickOutside(node, ignoreById) {
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        if (node && !node.contains(event.target) && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            node.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click_outside', node));
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);

    return {
        destroy() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
        }
    };
}
```

This is the `nav` element I am using the `clickOutside` function on

```
    <nav>
        <button class="menu-button" on:click={() => ($open = !$open)} aria-label="Open navigation menu">
            <div>
                <span
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    class={`${$open ? '-rotate-45 -translate-y-0' : '-translate-y-1.5'}`}
                />
                <span aria-hidden="true" class={`opacity-1 ${$open && 'opacity-0'}`} />
                <span
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    class={`${$open ? 'rotate-45 -translate-y-0' : 'translate-y-1.5'}`}
                />
            </div>
        </button>
        <div
            class="menu"
            class:open={$open}
            use:clickOutside
            on:click_outside={() => {
                $open === true && ($open = !$open);
            }}
        >
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <select on:change={(e) => (document.body.dataset.theme = e.target.value)}>
                <option value="pop-punk">Pop Punk</option>
                <option value="heavy-metal">Metal</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Clicking the menu button, opens the menu.
Clicking outside the menu, closes the menu.
Clicking the menu close button, doesn't close the menu.

I'm guessing this is because the menu button is layered on top of  the `div` that `use:clickOutisde` is applied to. What's the best way to fix this, I have tried using an `if document.querySelector('#menu-button'); return` type thing within the `useClickoutside` function to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that both the click-outside logic and the button logic trigger at the same time, negating each other.

You could fix this here by just moving the action/event handler to a common ancestor like the `<nav>` element.